# Obfuscation: JS protection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've been writing lots of code for many years, but in the past it's never been required to be protected, mainly because the code was written for clients and not myself.

I have lots of JavaScript & jQuery code that I have written, my biggest issues is that I have Ajax requests as well, and these communicate with internal PHP files.

## Here's a sample of code from Google:

```
function Yf(a, b, c) {
        c && (b = r(b, c));
        if (document.addEventListener) try {
                Zf(document, "DOMContentLoaded", b, a)
            } catch (d) {
                Zf(window, "load", b, a)
            } else if (!document.uniqueID && document.expando) var e = document.createElement("tempnode"),
                f = window.setInterval(function() {
                    try {
                        e.doScroll("left")
                    } catch (a) {
                        return
                    }
                    window.clearInterval(f);
                    f = e = null;
                    c && (b = r(b, c));
                    b()
                }, 50);
            else "readyState" in document ? f = window.setInterval(function() {
                    /loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState) && (window.clearInterval(f), f = null, c && (b = r(b, c)), b())
                },
                50) : Zf(window, "load", b, a)
    }
```

=====================================

Code comes from this url:
http://www.google.com/inbox/assets/js/main.min.js

Online JavaScript beautifier: 
http://jsbeautifier.org/

**Is this obfuscated or is it written this way from the beginning?** 
(Sure, one can follow along and read this code and other lines, but there's no evidence of any Ajax requests that are communicating with an (or several) internal page files)

Similar question might have been posted previously, but bear with me.

Comment: So you want to obfuscate the JavaScript as you are using AJAX? This doesn't make a lot of sense and it doesn't make your app more secure.

Comment: @Vohuman I am sure that when it comes to protection as a whole, it's not going to help a lot, as this has to do with the infrastructure that the website itself runs on and the core back-end code in PHP. Still I'd like to know if code like this is actually obfuscated or if it is written like this on purpose by Google Front-End Developers.

Comment: it's just minified, not obfuscated

Comment: Obviously the code had been minified and mangled. A tool like UglifyJS does this for you! "Security through obscurity" doesn't make your app more secure. The point of minifying client-side code is not security.

Comment: @charlietfl Hahaha! I see that it is minified, my issue is not minifying code. What I want to know is if code is written like this on purpose or if this is obfuscated? 

Major sites, Twitter, Google, Facebook, a few to mention, have their JS files written this way.

Comment: What "way" are you talking about? There's nothing about that code snippet that seems particularly obfuscated aside from variable names, really.

Comment: what do you mean by `written like this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, no.

All those single letter variables are often the result of running code through a JavaScript minifier.

JavaScript code gets sent to the browser over HTTP, so it's practice to make the code as compact as possible to save on bandwidth (which, in Google's case, can be *a lot*). This involves the use of a minifier, which acts like a compiler of sorts that takes existing JS code and transforms it and optimizes it to be functionally identical, but in a much smaller size.

For more detail you can see the [Wikipedia page on minification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)), which states:

> Minification (also minimisation or minimization), in computer
>   programming languages and especially JavaScript, is the process of
>   removing all unnecessary characters from source code without changing
>   its functionality. These unnecessary characters usually include white
>   space characters, new line characters, comments, and sometimes block
>   delimiters, which are used to add readability to the code but are not
>   required for it to execute.

Comment: Seriously? What type of JavaScript minifier outputs code like that?
(When I made my code minified, I usually only selected the entire code and chose format => 1 line) - I guess I did it wrong.

Comment: What type of JavaScript minifier outputs code like that?

Comment: "This involves the use of a minifier, which acts like a compiler of sorts that takes existing JS code and transforms it and optimizes it to be functionally identical, but in a much smaller size." 

Do I need this built-in on the web server where I am running the PHP code?

Comment: Usually it's part of an automated build/deploy step. A command line tool will take one or more JS files as input, and output a minified file which will be copied to the web server.

Comment: Yup, that's the one that really started it all :)

Comment: jsmin didn't do anything with the code? I ran it on a file, and this is the output: 
"'use strict';module.exports=Delegate;function Delegate(root){this.listenerMap=[{},{}];if(root){this.root(root);}
this.handle=Delegate.prototype.handle.bind(this);}
Delegate.prototype.root=function(root){var listenerMap=this.listenerMap;var eventType;if(this.rootElement){for(eventType in listenerMap[1]){if(listenerMap[1].hasOwnProperty(eventType)){this.rootElement.removeEventListener(eventType,this.handle,true);}

I see no changes to variable or class names etc?

Comment: To me it still looks like Google's own tools are far more powerful in comprising and minifying the javascript.

Comment: There are several minifiers/packers, each with varying levels of minification, such as jsmin (like you mentioned), [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS), [jspack](https://code.google.com/p/jspack/), the [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/), and probably several others.